My PHP Login Program keep denying to log in even though my password and username are correct
Note -> "akun" is usernam and "sandi" is the password
This is the login page :
<?php
session_start();
include("konekadmin.php");


?>

    <div class="container p-5" style="width: 50%">
      <div class="card shadow-sm">
        <div class="card-header">
          <br />
          <h4 class="text-center">Login</h4>
          <p class="text-center">Masuk ke akun admin SweetStay</p>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body p-5">
          <!--TODO: Form-->
          <form action="login.php" method="POST">
            <label for="text">Nama Akun</label>
            <input
              class="form-control"
              type="text"
              name="akun"
              placeholder="Nama Akun"
              required
              style="width: 100%"
            />
            <br />
            <label for="password">Kata Sandi</label>
            <input
              class="form-control"
              type="password"
              name="sandi"
              placeholder="Kata Sandi"
              required
              style="width: 100%"
            />
            <br />
            <br />

            <div class="row justify-content-center">
              <div class="col-auto">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="login">Login</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
        <div class="card-footer">
          <h5 class="text-center">
            Belum ada akun? <a href="registeradmin.php">Register</a>
          </h5>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
   

This is connection php :
<?php
$hostname = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$password = "";
$db_name = "admin";

$kon = mysqli_connect($hostname,$user,$password,$db_name) or die(mysqli_error($kon));


This is the login system :
<?php
session_start();
include("konekadmin.php");

if(isset($_POST['login'])){
    $akun = $_POST["akun"];
    $sandi = $_POST["sandi"];

    $hasil = mysqli_query($kon, "SELECT * FROM tb_admin WHERE akun = '$akun'");
    if(mysqli_num_rows($hasil) > 0){
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($hasil);
        if(password_verify($sandi, $row["sandi"])){
            $_SESSION['status'] = "Swal.fire({ title: 'Berhasil Login Akun!', icon: 'success'})";
            header("location: index.php");
            exit();
        }

        else {
            $_SESSION['status'] = "Swal.fire({ title: 'Gagal Login!', icon: 'error'})";
            header("location: loginadmin.php");
        }
    }

  }




Additional, this the register page :
<?php
include("konekadmin.php");
session_start();
?>
<
    <div class="container p-5" style="width: 50%">
      <div class="card shadow-sm">
        <div class="card-header">
          <br />
          <h4 class="text-center">Register</h4>
          <p class="text-center">Register akun admin SweetStay</p>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body p-5">
          <form action="data.php" method="POST">
            <label for="text">Nama</label>
            <input
              class="form-control"
              type="text"
              name="nama"
              placeholder="Nama Anda"
              required
              style="width: 100%"
            />
            <br />
            <label for="text">Nama Akun</label>
            <input
              class="form-control"
              type="text"
              name="akun"
              placeholder="Nama Akun"
              required
              style="width: 100%"
            />
            <br />
            <label for="text">Email</label>
            <input
              class="form-control"
              type="email"
              name="email"
              placeholder="Email"
              required
              style="width: 100%"
            />
            <br />
            <label for="text">No. HP</label>
            <input
              class="form-control"
              type="text"
              name="hp"
              placeholder="Nomor Handphone"
              required
              style="width: 100%"
            />
            <br />
            <label for="password">Kata Sandi</label>
            <input
              class="form-control"
              type="password"
              name="sandi"
              placeholder="Kata Sandi"
              required
              style="width: 100%"
            />
            <br />
            <label for="password">Konfirmasi Kata Sandi</label>
            <input
              class="form-control"
              type="password"
              name="konsandi"
              placeholder="Konfirmasi Sandi"
              required
              style="width: 100%"
            />

            <br />

            <div class="row justify-content-center">
              <div class="col-auto">
                <input
                  class="btn btn-primary"
                  type="submit"
                  name="register"
                  value="Register"
                />
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
        <div class="card-footer">
          <h5 class="text-center">
            Sudah ada akun? <a href="loginadmin.php">Masuk</a>
          </h5>
        </div>

And this is the register system :
<?php
session_start();
include("konekadmin.php");

if(isset($_POST['registeradmin'])){
    $nama = $_POST['nama'];
    $akun = $_POST['akun'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $hp = $_POST['hp'];
    $sandi = $_POST['sandi'];
    $konsandi = $_POST['konsandi'];

    $cek_akun = mysqli_query($kon,"SELECT * FROM tb_admin WHERE akun='$akun'");
    $cek_login = mysqli_num_rows($cek_akun);

    if($cek_login > 0) {
        $_SESSION['status'] = "Swal.fire({ title: 'Nama Akun Sudah Ada', text: 'Coba nama lain', icon: 'error'})";
        header("location: tambahadmin.php");
    }

    else {
        if($sandi != $konsandi){
            $_SESSION['status'] = "Swal.fire({ title: 'Konfirmasi Password Tidak Sama', text: 'Coba ulangi lagi', icon: 'error'})";
            header("location: tambahadmin.php");
        }

        else {
            $san = password_hash($sandi,PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
            mysqli_query($kon,"INSERT INTO tb_admin VALUES('','$nama','$akun','$email','$hp','$san')");
            $_SESSION['status'] = "Swal.fire({ title: 'Berhasil Daftar Akun!', icon: 'success'})";
            header("location: admin.php");
        }
    }
}

Lastly this is the admin page where we should arrive after logging in :
<?php
include("keperluan/head.php");
?>
                <h5><i class="fa fa-gear"></i> Admin Teregister</h5> 
    <?php
    include("keperluan/feet.php");
    ?>

Can anyone help point out what did I do wrong until it wont let me log in?
I already try changing any part of the code but nothing working, and I was expecting it to just head me back to the admin page

Please edit this down to a Minimum Reproducible Example - there's a lot of code to wade through there. I'm pretty sure all that CSS in the first code block isn't affecting the problem.

Is your password column long enough to store the hashed password? You also need to read up on Prepared Statements instead of just concatenating all those strings into your queries. What happens if someone registers with the name "Terry O'Hara"?

What actually happens when you try to log in? What is the actual code path, and does that not show you where (and why) it is failing?

In your registration code, instead of running a query to check whether a username already exists, you should give the username column a unique constraint, attempt to insert the new row, and handle the "duplicate column" error if there is one. Doing it your way might still allow a duplicate if two people attempt to register almost at the same time if the column is not unique.

oh you're right, seem my column wasnt enough with holding the hashed. i tried to increase the size and i finnaly can logged in. thank you for that, i really appreciate it

Not sure where you've been learning from, but this is totally the wrong way to build a SQL query using PHP when you're incorporating user input into it. 1) It's vulnerable to SQL injection attacks, and 2) it can be crashed with simple syntax issues due to the input values  - e.g. anyone with a ' in their name (such as O'Reilly)  would crash your query because SQL would think the ' was terminating the input string after the O.

Instead you must use prepared statements and parameters to correctly build the query and insert the values safely. See How to include a PHP variable inside a MySQL statement, How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP? and https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli for some excellent resources and simple examples of how to do this stuff properly. Even as a beginner on a practice project you should get into good habits.
